# Getting input type="text" value and call c# method onchange without Posting or leaving the page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, razor-pages

I am trying to call a c# method from input type="text" onchange and passing its text value as well.

The html code looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="test" onchange="@Model.myMethod(test.value)" />
where test.value I want to pass the text value as well as a parameter.
myMethod gets some data from database and fills a Dictionary.
```

I want afterwards(after onchange) to display a table with some data that the method returned.

I know there must be simplier way with ajax call but I do not know the way either.

Comment: I'm afraid ajax or may be a good choice,if you don't want to leave or refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using ajax.

```
function checkDates()
    {

    var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
           $.ajax({
            data:{dateselected: date},
            url:'/my-page?handler=SelectDates',
            type:'GET',
            success: function (data)
            {
            if(Object.keys(data).length === 0)
            {
             document.getElementById('example').value = "Some Value";
            }
            else
            {
               //Doing my stuff
            }
            },
            error: function () 
             {
               alert("error");
             }
          })
     }
```

And the Model class contains the following IActionResult

```
      [HttpGet]
       public IActionResult OnGetSelectDates(string dateselected)
       {
         MyService.myFunction(dateselected);
         mydict = MyService.dict;
         return new JsonResult(mydict);
       }
```

And the cshtml contains the following

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control input datepicker" placeholder="@now" id="date" name="date" onchange="checkdates()">
```